# Error in hierarchical clustering with hcluster in python

Tags: python, attributeerror, hcluster

I am trying to ran the following code, and I get an AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hcluster', raised in the last line.

I am running in Mountain Lion, I use pip and homebrew, and hcluster is in PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Any idea what can be going wrong? Thanks.

```
import os 
import hcluster
from numpy import *
from PIL import Image
# create a list of images
path = 'data/flickr-sunsets-small'
imlist = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.jpg')]
# extract feature vector (8 bins per color channel)
features = zeros([len(imlist), 512])
for i,f in enumerate(imlist):
    im = array(Image.open(f))
    # multi-dimensional histogram
    h,edges = histogramdd(im.reshape(-1,3),8,normed=True,range=[(0,255),(0,255),(0,255)]) 
    features[i] = h.flatten()
tree = hcluster.hcluster(features)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means that Python cannot find the function/class `hcluster` in the
module `hcluster`, so when you do `tree = hcluster.hcluster(features)` it complains.

I'm not familiar with this module, but I had a quick look at this it, and it lists a function called `fcluster`, but no `hcluster`.